# How to read the file in the encoding of win1251?

Tags: dart, command-line-interface, dart-pub

I need to read the file in the encoding win1251 and convert it to UTF8.

Is it possible on dat?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you need an [Encoding](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.69.5/dart-convert/Encoding-class.html) that supports win1251

We ship several converters in the Dart SDK, but not win1251 specifically. You might want to try the [Latin1Codec](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.69.5/dart-convert/Latin1Codec-class.html). It seems to [overlap with win1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) quite a bit.

The example in the [`dart:convert`](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.69.5/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) API page should be a good start:

```
int lineNumber = 1;
Stream<List<int>> stream = new File('quotes.txt').openRead();

stream.transform(utf8.decoder)
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .listen((line) {
        if (showLineNumbers) {
          stdout.write('${lineNumber++} ');
        }
        stdout.writeln(line);
      });
```

...except use `latin1.decoder` instead of `utf8.decoder`.